# C# static Main(string[] args)

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

Hi I'm trying to learn some C# programming and I came across something that I'm having a difficult time understanding. I usually deal with VB6, VB.NET, and VBA for the most part so I have some understanding of programming. Here's what I'm not sure about...

Let's say you have two snippets of code...

1)

```
static int Area(int h, int w)
{
 return h*w;
}
```

2)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
 int res = Area(w: 5, h: 8);
 Console.WriteLine(res);
 }
```

So in the first snippet, I'm doing the return which does the multiplication of H * W but we do not write it as we do in the #2 with `Console.WriteLine()`?

What does the return actually do?

In #2 - the first line `static void Main(string[] args)` - especially the string[] args part - What does this mean?

Comment: What your asking is the the basics of programming , its not a simple question or can be answered here, try learn from toturials before you start asking questions like this.

Comment: albeit answers here are legit and kind in nature I really think that this level of questions really should be addressed by referencing a manual or tutorial. otherwise those questions will go on forever and ever...

Comment: Okay closing it as soon as SO will let me.

Comment: If i'm going to get thumbs down on this question, let me know so I delete it. I sincerely apologize for asking such a unworthy question. So before you press the button, leave a comment and I'll delete it. Seems like people are very angry with me because i asked a beginner question - where I am in fact trying to learn programming. Ridiculous. The quesiton is closed, and I guarantee that it will get hundreds if not thousands of view very shortly as there are others who are asking the same question.

Comment: @BobSki I doubt many people are upset or angry with you! It is of course frustrating seeing questions that do not meet SO guidelines, and to allow basic questions (e.g., what is `return`?) that are already thoroughly answered elsewhere will crowd out more pertinent questions that this site is intended for. Votes are merely there to indicate this question doesn't meet the standard for SO. It certainly doesn't mean your question isn't valid nor important!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So in the first snippet, I'm doing the return which does the multiplication of H * W but we do not write it as we do in the #2 with console.writeline? What does the return actually do?

`return` represents what the function will return when called. The two parameters, `h*w`, must be supplied when the function is called, or a compiler error will be thrown. It's like an algebraic expression; the function represents that without needing to show the logic, just input two numbers and the functionality is applied as the return variable from the function. Using your example:

```
int res = Area(w: 5, h: 8)
```

Here, the function is called `Area(w: 5, h: 8)`, with the `w` variable set to `5` and the `h` set to `8`. Back to our function then:

```
static int Area(int h, int w)
{
  return h*w;
}
```

replace the variables, and you get:

```
static int Area(int h, int w)
{
   return 8*5;
}
```

So, it shouldn't surprise you that `res = Area(w: 5, h: 8)` gives `res` as `40`, when you log it in the console.

> In #2 - the first line static void Main(string[] args) - especially the string []args part - what does this mean?

The `string[] args` represents an array of arguments sent to the `Main` function, which is especially useful once you compile your script into an `.exe`. From the command line, you could do:

```
compiled.exe "My" "Strings"
```

and the array would contain two values; `args[0] == "My"` and `args[1] == "Strings"`. You can loop through the `args[]` array to utilise them. In this script, the `args` array is not used.

**EDIT** Comment correction.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation!

Comment: The two values example should be args[0] == "My" and args[1] == "Strings".

Comment: @BogadoDiego Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

1) `return` is a keyword meant to determine the **result** of a function/method. In your case, the method is called `Area`. [See Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx).

2) `args` is a string array that will contain all parameters that you pass to your program when you're running it from a command line. [See Command-line arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb20e19t.aspx). Example:

```
foo.exe -a -b
```

In the above case, the `args` array will be `["-a", "-b"]`

Comment: Thank you this helped. Thanks for the links.

Comment: @Bobski I'm glad I helped.

Comment: @andrerpena This isn't correct. The args will be `-a` and `-b`. See the reference you've linked and take a look at the code example.

Answer (score 1):

1. `return` returns a value from the function to the caller, so e.g. you can assign the result of the function call to a variable.
2. `string[] args` is an array of arguments passed to the program if you run it from command line.

Answer (score 1):

The return passes back the answer in this case it will give the h*w back to the main mether where the area method is called

String[] args refers to arguments that can be passed into the main method in this case an array of strings, this can be passed in by whatever is calling this main method.